# How to download a complete web page (with all its contents) in Java?

Tags: java, html, download, save

Using Java, I need to save a complete webpage(with all its contents like images, css, javascript e.t.c) like how we can do with save as-->complete webpage option with HttpClient lib. How can I do this?

Comment: Related: [Fetch complete web page using java code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10119998), [How can I download web page with dependencies in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4318616), [download a complete web page including resources (like images) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4359060), [download webpage and dependencies, including css images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1581551).

Answer (score 0):

You can try lib curl java 
[http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/java/](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/java/.)

And you can refer to this discussion also 
[curl-equivalent-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116650/curl-equivalent-in-java/116725#116725)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write an application that fetches the html file, parses it and extracts all the references, and then fetches all the files found by parsing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so easy because some CSS/JS/Images files paths might be "hidden". Just consider the following example:

```
<script type="...">
   document.write("&bla;script" + " type='...' src='" + blahBlah() + "'&bla;" + "&bla;/script&bla;");
</script>
```

However, fetching page source, parsing in the search for URLs and downloading founded URLs is pretty everything you'll probably need.