# How can I download web page with dependencies in Java?

Tags: java, wget

How can I download web page with dependencies in Java-code so that it renders the same way locally as online? (Excluding Ajax). I've heard that wget can do this, but I'm looking for some java-code that can do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of (open source) web crawlers: http://java-source.net/open-source/crawlers which you can either use to do this, or can peek at the code to see how it can be done.

Comment: I'm actually using WebSphinx, but I can't find out how to do it with the class library (it's easy from the workbench) even though I have spent some good time in the doc and googling for examples. Its pretty annoying when I know it has the functionality, I just can't find it! ;) I will check out some of the others as well.

Comment: @Kris, I'm not familiar with that crawler, but glancing over the API, I guess you'd need to create a `Crawler` instance and follow the steps outlined in the API: http://www-2.cs.cmu.edu/~rcm/websphinx/doc/websphinx/Crawler.html

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I'm not struggling to do the crawling itself (i have successfully set up the crawler), but rather how to save the page locally with dependencies so it renders ok. This could either be done by downloading the css and images linked in the "main-page" or making sure the local copy is written with absolute URLs (in HTML and CSS). I was hoping i didn't have to write the code for this myself :)