# download a complete web page including resources (like images) in java

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

is there a way to download (html) web page and all it's resources (eg: images,CSS).

I know how to do this using a html parser, by going through all the relevant tags, but isn't there a **easy way**?

Comment: You have some answers here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318616/how-can-i-download-web-page-with-dependencies-in-java

Comment: Look at Jobo, http://www.matuschek.net/jobo/, an open source web crawler

Comment: thank, I hope I can pull some code form one of these projects

Answer (score 1):

That *is* the easy way.

The hard way is to write your own network libraries, html parser etc...

Comment: @Manu - I understood that, however, I don't know of any framework that does that. The problem is fairly trivial.