# Fetch complete web page using java code

Tags: java, javascript, html-parsing, jsoup

I want to implement a java method which takes URL as input and stores the entire webpage including css, images, js (all related resources) on my disk. I have used Jsoup html parser to fetch html page. Now the only option I am thinking to implement is get the page using jsoup and now parse the html content and convert relative path to absolute path and then make another get requests for javascript, images etc. and save them on disk.
I also read about html cleaner, htmlunit parsers but i think in all these cases I have to parse the html content to fetch images,css and javascript files.

Any advice whether i am thinking right or not.
Or is there any easy way to accomplish this task ??

Comment: I found out some similar questions on SO but answer to this question is still unanswered :(

Comment: Your thinking is exactly right. You might like to look at some of the source code for Apache Nutch; which is a search engine. The indexing part fetches web pages, then scans them for links (and does a whole lot of other stuff too). The code that you want will be similar but not identical.

Comment: How did you fix this? could you get what you want

Comment: @Clara_57S Yes, I used jsoup and it solved the problem for me.

Comment: but it cant execute javascript.

Comment: @Clara_57S, if you are still interested since this is recently fresh comment, you can combine HtmlUnit we client fetch HtmlPage and then just parse with Jsoup.parse(HtmlPage.asXml()). This way you can get html after all JavaScript has executed and do what you need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you can do it with Jsoup:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://rabotalux.com.ua/vacancy/4f4f800c8bc1597dc6fc7aff").get();
         Elements links = doc.select("link");
         Elements scripts = doc.select("script");
        for (Element element : links) {
              System.out.println(element.absUrl("href"));
        }
        for (Element element : scripts) {
              System.out.println(element.absUrl("src"));
        }
```

And so on with images and all related resources.

**BUT** if your site creates some elements with javaScript, Jsoup will skip it, as it cant execute javaScript

Comment: hey vacuum, Does this absUrl function print only elements' url which have absolute path only. I want to fetch relative paths also and convert them to absolute path. Does such similar functionality exist in Jsoup or i have to do it manually

Comment: its do it too. From JavaDoc:
`String org.jsoup.nodes.Node.absUrl(String attributeKey)
Get an absolute URL from a URL attribute that may be relative (i.e. an <a href> or <img src>). 
E.g.: String absUrl = linkEl.absUrl("href"); 
If the attribute value is already absolute (i.e. it starts with a protocol, like http:// or https:// etc), and it successfully parses as a URL, the attribute is returned directly. Otherwise, it is treated as a URL relative to the element's baseUri, and made absolute using that.

Comment: @blunderboy  [link] (http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#absUrl(java.lang.String))

Comment: Thanks vaccum, I have read that :) and followed the same which you have suggested..thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the similar problem before couple of years where we have used exactly the same mechanism which you are planing. parse the html content and convert relative path to absolute path and also we have used multiple threads to run simultaneously and retrieve images, java script etc for performance optimization. I don't know it should done as we did or not but at the end it works for us.:-)

Answer (score 1):

[This GitHub project](https://github.com/PramodKhare/GetMeThatPage) does this, using jSoup. No need to write it again if it already exists!

EDIT: I made an [improved](https://github.com/JonasCz/save-for-offline/blob/master/app/src/main/java/jonas/tool/saveForOffline/PageSaver.java) version of this class, and added new features :

It can:

- Extract URL's from Linked or Inline CSS, eg. for background images, and download & save those too.
- It does multithreaded downloading of all the files, (images, scripts, etc.)
- Gives details about progress and errors.
- Can get HTML frames embedded in the HTML document, and nested frames also.

Some caveats:

- Uses [JSoup](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), so you need to have those libraries.
- GPL licenced, for now anyway.