# Why shouldn't wget fetch the response content of a 500 response?

Tags: http, curl, wget

This question is a follow-up of [HTTP 500 error in wget](/questions/6083102/http-500-error-in-wget)

Upon server errors `wget` will *not* fetch the content of the reponse, whereas `curl` *should* be used for that purpose.

Indeed `curl`, or any web browser, does load the content as well in case of 50X exit code.

So I was indeed curious to better understand why `wget` will not load the content anyway, with none of the lots of options it has: usually servers send an error explanation along, so why ignore it?

Comment: I don't know "why" but `--content-on-error` option will fix the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57779851/7784017

Answer (score 0):

According to http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?27303#comment4, wget already has the feature (downloading error pages) in the development version.