# wget downloads CSS @import, but ignores files referenced within them

Tags: css, wget

I'm using `wget` as follows:

```
wget --page-requisites --convert-links -e robots=off \
     --span-hosts --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --directory-prefix=$ASSETS_DIR --no-directories http://myhost/home
```

The HTML page references a stylesheet file `application.css` which includes the following:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:700);
```

wget properly creates a file `css@family=Quicksand%3A700` with the following contents:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Quicksand Bold'), local('Quicksand-Bold'), url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/quicksand/v3/32nyIRHyCu6iqEka_hbKsonF5uFdDttMLvmWuJdhhgs.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

However, wget does not download the actual TTF file referenced here. When I change the CSS on the page being mirrored and paste the `@font-face` rule directly to `application.css`, it downloads the TTF file. (But I don't want to do that – I prefer to keep using `@import` pointed at Google Fonts).

Is there a way to force `wget` to parse the `@import`ed stylesheet and download its references too?

Answer (score 4):

Try `wget -m -p -E -k -K -np http:\\mysite.com`. I had the same problem and this solution worked for me: [download webpage and dependencies, including css images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581551/download-webpage-and-dependencies-including-css-images)

Comment: How is that different from the command pasted in the question? It already includes `--page-requisites` flag.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it right after. Probably didn't go through due to my bad connection